# Built-in way of getting SuppressFBWarnings value for error message

Tags: eclipse, findbugs

I have configured Eclipse to find bugs using FindBugs. Now I get some error messages in the *Markers* window. I reviewed them and for a few, I'd like to introduce a *SuppressFBWarnings* annotation.

**How do I obtain the ID for the *value* attribute of SuppressFBWarnings in Eclipse?**

I know I can go to [the FindBugs description page](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html), click the item and get the ID, but I wonder whether there's a shorter built-in way. I have already checked whether there is an additional column to be displayed in the *Markers* window, but there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right-click the item in the "Markers" window
2. Choose "Show Bug Info" from the menu
3. Scroll to the bottom and get the text near "Pattern:"